# Facing overflow issue with react slick

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-slick

I am using react slick for slider and that slider cards contain dropdown that have lot of options. When the dropdown is open half of the dropdown is cropped not able to view the full dropdown

code pen: https://codepen.io/gtm18/pen/YzRdaML (demo with jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.carousel').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  dots:true,
  centerMode: true,
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the height of the dropdown so the scroll will be added and you can see all the options like this,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.carousel').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    dots:true,
    centerMode: true,
  });
})();

// Slick version 1.5.8
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html, body{
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
.wrapper{
  width:100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align:center;
}
h2{
  font-family:sans-serif;
  color:#fff;
}
.carousel{
  width:90%;
  margin:0px auto;
}
.slick-slide{
  margin:10px;
}
.slick-slide img{
  width:100%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}
.wrapper .slick-dots li button:before {
  font-size:20px;
  color:white;
}
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

#myInput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myInput:focus {outline: 3px solid #ddd;}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  min-width: 230px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
  max-height: 240px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2>Slick Carousel Example</h2>
  <div class="carousel">
    <div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">
          Dropdown
        </button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search.."
            id="myInput"
            onkeyup="filterFunction()"
          />
          <a href="#about">About</a>
          <a href="#base">Base</a>
          <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
          <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
          <a href="#support">Support</a>
          <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <select name="cars" id="cars">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <select name="cars" id="cars">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?random=4" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?random=5" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?random=6" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The demo isn't working for me - no scrollbar. Could you check it? Also, put it in the answer, not on an external site which may disappear at any time.

Comment: Yes, I have added the working snippet here

Comment: Thanks. I now see the scrollbar on the dropdown.